# DRF Serializer doesn't raise error in update but doesn't update

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, django-serializer

I have a model with a foreign key I'm trying to update via the serializer, I don't want to use the built-in ID field to find the foreign key.
My Serializer code seems to be working fine, no error is being raised but it doesn't update the foreign key field.

Models:

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    farm = models.ForeignKey(to=Farm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name=RelatedNames.GROUPS,
                             default=None, null=True, blank=True, )

    milking = models.BooleanField(help_text=GroupHelpTexts.MILKING)
    sub_groups = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name=RelatedNames.SUBGROUPS,
                                   null=True, blank=True, )


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Cow(models.Model):
    management_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    eid_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, blank=False, )

    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                              default=None, null=True, blank=True, related_name=RelatedNames.COWS)
```

My serializer:

```py
class CowManagementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='group_id', queryset=Group.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Cow
        fields = ['management_id', 'eid_number', 'group']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['group']:
            try:
                name = attrs['group']
                user = self.context['request'].user
                group = Group.objects.get(name=name, farm__user=user)
                attrs['group'] == group
                return attrs
            except Group.DoesNotExist:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Group Not Found")
        return attrs

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        group = validated_data.pop('group')
        instance.group = group
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

If I remove the slug related field I get this error:

```
{
  "group": [
    "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
  ]
}
```

with it, I get a 200 status code but no update is being made.

Comment: Not sure about your db config, but `group_id` from `Group` model won't be its primary key, just some custom CharField column. Could you possibly share some entries from your db? You update them via standard django form, right?

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski not using Form, only as API.
I know it's not a primary key but this the field I want to filter by, is it not possible to update without a primary key?